# Pretty tricky cmd

Tags: shell, command, pipe

I was searching for a cmd to generate random passwords, and got stuck on this one :

```
echo `< /dev/urandom tr -dc _A-Z-a-z-0-9 | head -c6`
```

I've read the documentation of `urandom`, `tr` and `head`. But could you explain step by step how all these are linked in this cmd ?

I've tried `` echo `< /dev/urandom` `` to experiment, and my terminal just crashed !

Comment: Just install the "apg" package.

Comment: Thanks @EEAA . But I'm not looking for a generator, I'd like to understand this particular cmd.

Comment: Have you read the man pages for all of those commands?

Comment: [A few articles on this site will answer your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=urandom+tr+)

Comment: I think you may have the command off a little. 

`< /dev/urandom tr -dc _A-Z-a-z-0-9 | head -c6`

Is more likely I think. So lets break it down:

`< /dev/urandom` This just says connect urandom to stdin. As you probably know urandom generates random bytes (but will give you bytes even if the entropy pool is empty).

`tr -dc _A-Z-a-z-0-9` Just deletes (`-d`) anything **not** (`-c`) part of the set that includes upper and lower letters and the numbers 0-9. 

`head -c6` Finally, head takes only the first 6 characters (`-c6`)

Comment: as well as `apg`, there's also `makepasswd` and `pwgen` and many others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, I'd guess the command uses `` echo `...` `` for the sole purpose of sticking a newline at the end of the output. It doesn't seem have any other effect.

That reduces the actual command to:

```
< /dev/urandom tr -dc _A-Z-a-z-0-9 | head -c6
```

`tr -dc _A-Z-a-z-0-9` deletes every character from the input except for those given (underscore, alphabets and digits, and the hyphen, because the author added extra hyphens). `< /dev/urandom` indicates `tr` is reading in from `/dev/urandom`. Finally, `head -c6` extracts the first 6 characters that are output by `tr`.

On the whole, it is a ridiculous way to generate passwords.

Comment: Right. I would have understood `cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc _A-Z-a-z-0-9 | head -c6` but I'm not very familiar with the structure `< cmd1 cmd2` which seems equivalent. Thanks.

Comment: This is actually pretty close to how I generate, except I use base64 to be less wasteful of entropy. (And six characters isn't near enough.)